# IntelliJ and Websphere7 won't connect through SOAP

Tags: intellij-idea, websphere

I can't manage to remote deploy anything to Websphere 7 using the remote config in IntelliJ.

I tried to configure the server connection in all possible ways, with no success. I copied the trust and key store from the server into a local directory, change the soap.client.props from the WAS conf, with no success. The most frequent error I have is:

```
Error connecting to the Application Server:
     com.intellij.javaee.process.common.WrappedException: com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConnectorException: ADMC0016E: Le système n'a pas pu créer de connecteur SOAP pour la connexion à l'hôte PC110014305 sur le port 8881. Root cause: [SOAPException: faultCode=SOAP-ENV:Client; msg=Error parsing HTTP status line " ": java.util.NoSuchElementException; targetException=java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error parsing HTTP status line " ": java.util.NoSuchElementException]
```

Has anyone successfully manage to remotely connect to a distant WAS?

Comment: I get the same error. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope. I opened a ticket at JetBrains, but they couldn't find a solution. I guess WAS 7 is too old.